# What will be regex expression

Tags: python, regex

Hi Can anyone help me in deciding regex expression for following:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.google.com"?>
```

i am trying folwing but not working:

```
r'<[?](xml-stylesheet)[?]>'
```

Comment: explain the issue a bit more. What are you trying and what is not working? specify the language as well.

Comment: @user34 you mean this http://regex101.com/r/wG4jR8/4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are trying to match  `<?xml-stylesheet` tag. If yes, then you could try the below code

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """
... foo
... <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.google.com"?>
... bar"""
>>> re.search(r'<\?xml-stylesheet[^>]*?\?>', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f452c365370>
>>> m = re.search(r'<\?xml-stylesheet[^>]*?\?>', s)
>>> m.group()
'<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.google.com"?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/uG8gO1/2))

```
<\?xml-stylesheet.*?\?>
```

Comment: not sure if a valid edge case for OP, but this also matches `<?xml-stylesheet type=text/xsl" href=http://www.google.com"?>`, which is malformed (quotes are not right).

Comment: @mu無 uhm.. if the OP wants to check also for validity he he should use an html parser. In the question is not clear what he's trying to accomplish.